# customer display on headless server / POS system / Mac OSX

Tags: terminal, osx, display

I have a web based POS system running (AMP), formerly on debian, now switched to OSX due to lacking linux printer drivers.
The Mac mini is running headless, no keyboard, no mouse, no (normal) monitor.

The POS program itself is running in the browser on any iPad or android over WiFi.

Now I have the idea to attach a 7inch or whatever customer display to the server, where actual purchasing results are displayed in realtime. I can be a simple b&w terminal display like on the sample image.

[image: customer display]

As I am totally not familiar with terminal displays and scripts... what would be the best approach?

I could provide a text file anywhere in the file system which contains the data to be shown, but how to display?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: additional info: It would be nice, if font sizes could be adjusted, not just the regular small console font appearance.

Comment: @drewbenn Sorry I don't get it. As far as I understand, your suggestion means a script which runs any other command repeatedly. Well, the first step. But how actually do I read a text file and send it to an attached monitor ? How this monitor is detected ? As additional info, let's say, the same Mac mini is used in normal graphical mode as a normal desktop with keyboard and monitor, how a 2nd small monitor is getting the data ?

Comment: oops, drewbenn deleted his link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574089/osx-bash-watch-command , here again, to be complete. But how can I use this ?